# Spring Boot + newRelic

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic

Is there any links that shows a demo of spring boot+ newRelic+ Maven. I would like to try integrate both to try and test a sample app for checking newRelic feature.

Comment: I am looking for a sample application integrating Spring Boot + newrelic . That would be useful :) . I have looked into the app with gradle , Since I havent worked in gradle not able to follow much in that . Can u suggest any sample build with maven.

Comment: I had asked this question to New Relic support a few weeks ago.  It is not something they support at this time.  You could try and engage New Relic support for help.  We are using Microservices and their APM pricing model was a show stopper so we did not pursue getting things to work with Spring Boot.  Choosing to just monitor the servers instead and use Actuator for app information.

Answer (score 0):

What about this [example project](https://github.com/jkubrynski/spring-boot-new-relic-agent)?

Author added NewRelic dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Unpacked dependency to have all files in jar:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeArtifactIds>newrelic-agent</includeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Extended maven jar plugin config, to have important attributes in place:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <configuration>
     <archive>
       <manifestEntries>
         <Premain-Class>com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent</Premain-Class>
         <Can-Redefine-Classes>true</Can-Redefine-Classes>
         <Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
       </manifestEntries>
     </archive>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Pointed out main class of the app:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <mainClass>com.kubrynski.blog.newrelic.SpringBootNewRelicApplication</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the packaged jar (springBoot + newRelic) work for you.

In my opinion it will NOT work.
As the packaged jar contains newRelic.jar
inside a Zip (which is in /BOOT-INF/lib)
and not simply inside /BOOT-INF/lib like other dependencies.

[Please see here](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/java-build-with-maven-and-include-new-relic/189288)

thank you